# Android Sip application call from Contacts / PhoneBook

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-contacts

I'm currently developing an application using sip which is actually working.

However, I would like to allow people to call from "PhoneBook/Contact",

I saw a few application, like csip simple, where it works. I can click on the phone number, then a little dialog box appears and I can choose between several application.

[image: Example here]

I already did some research on StackOverflow and I found one solution which does not work.

I wonder if I made a mistake in my manifest, could you help me ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.example.SIPProject" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="10">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIALER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.sip.SipManagerService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.example.sip.SipOnboot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <service android:name="com.example.sip.SipManagerService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.example.sip.SipOnboot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <use-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
    <use-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
    <use-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SIP calls, i think the data type should be like this
`<data android:scheme="sip" />`

For reference check this
[SipDroid](https://github.com/sunnyqeen/sipdroid/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you however  I would like that my application understood the tel scheme 
too.

I have also checked SipDroid documentation and CSipSimple source code.

Besides my application has all permissions in the application settings but she can't be set like phone call default applications on Android 5.02